# Error #1932 with MySQL in phpMyAdmin database and XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling, phpmyadmin, xampp

Recently my XAMPP -> MySQL started crashing for unknown reason and I was needed to reinstall xampp, but since error was unexpected I could not make database backup nor dump of database.
All I managed to save was xampp/phpMyAdmin folder in xampp and xampp/mysql/data folder. When I copied data folder in mysql I got my database back with tables but there was no records in the tables and the error when I click on table is "#1932 - Table 'mydatabase.mytable' doesn't exist in engine".
Please tell me is there some way to fix it or just restor records from tables, becouse I have some files in data folder I saved, those files have name of every table and there are 2 of them .FRM and .IBD.
Is there some way I can restor just records from those files.

Thank you very much for putting time aside to read this and helping me. Thank you.
P.S. Please dont get any points with fixing my text, just give me solution if you know or comment and I will get back to you if you need any more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in ibdata1 file.
If you have old copy of that file copy it over new one and if you dont than check this post it was very helpful.
Thank everyone who put time aside to read this.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/restoring-mysql-tables-from-ibd-frm-and-mysqllogbin-files